# App scripts email notification after keyword input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My University accommodation has started to log incoming mail on a Google Sheets document.

Instead of checking every day, I just want an email notification to be sent to my Gmail every time my room number "93A" is input into a cell.

Can someone share some code for setting this up, or point me in the right direction for getting this setup as simple as possible?

Comment: Hey Ben, welcome to SO! Can you tell us what you have tried so far? I suggest you read the [following article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IFTTT service for this. Check out this link - [cell update in google sheets notification](https://ifttt.com/applets/483113p-cell-update-in-google-sheets-send-notification)